# AngularJS google chart dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

**Example**

[Try it on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hMnKAzjbkQzHWjL5p6KX?p=previewangularjs)

I'm trying to put together the graphics with dynamic data, because I get the webservice and looks like this:

```
var avaliacoes_descTipo = [];
var avaliacoes_quantidade = [];

angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) { 
                this.push(key + ': ' + value);
                avaliacoes_descTipo[key] = value.descTipo;
                avaliacoes_quantidade[key] = value.quantidade;
            }, log_avaliacoes);



And I no fixed place for example<br>
  **{w: [
                     {V: avaliacoes_descTipo [1]},
                     {V: avaliacoes_quantidade [1]}
                 ]}<br>
                 {w: [
                     {V: avaliacoes_descTipo [2]},
                     {V: avaliacoes_quantidade [2]}
                 ]}
]};**
```

Need your help to put dynamic, with foreach do not know any way to work will help me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this way:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   var avaliacoes_descTipo = ["1", "12", "13"];
   var avaliacoes_quantidade = [1,2,3];
   var val = [];
   var i;
   var val1 = [];
$scope.avaliacoes = {};

for (i = 0; i < avaliacoes_descTipo.length; i++) {
  val = {c: [
    {v: avaliacoes_descTipo[i]},
    {v: avaliacoes_quantidade[i]}
  ]};

  val1.push(val);
}

$scope.avaliacoes.type = "PieChart";

$scope.onions = [
  {v: avaliacoes_descTipo[0]},
  {v: avaliacoes_quantidade[0]}
];

$scope.avaliacoes.data = {"cols": [
  {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
  {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
], "rows":
  val1

};

$scope.avaliacoes.options = {
  'title': '',
  'legend' : {'position': 'bottom'}
};

});
```